# Mac OS 11.2.1 Big sur- git version control Rstudio path -unable to edit . Not able to link

Tags: r, git, github

I am new to Version control and this is my first attempt. I am also a novice in R. just did an online course. I have installed Git and was trying to add the Version control through Rstudio Global options. The Git executable file path shows "user/bin/git" But when I go to create a Project>version control>Git- I get an error "Git was not detected on the path" I dug deeper and ran cmd in the mac terminal- `which git` and got the location as "/usr/local/bin/git", I also did a `$ git --exec-path` and got the location as "/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/libexec/git-core" I understand the executable path is somewhere else. I understand that I need to change the path but Rstudio is not allowing the changing of the path, and I am unable to edit the path to "/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.30.0/libexec/git-core" from "user/bin/git". I tried manually entering but that doesnt work, I browsed through the file s and sub folders and selected the executable file location , but it still doesnt change. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow: You can find a step by step support on the official support site of rstudio. Here you get detailed instructions on how to use version control with RStudio: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN

Comment: Hi. None of this worked. But what I found this link help fun- Downloaded Xcode and it started working all fine. https://ma.ttias.be/mac-os-xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-missing-xcrun/

Comment: @Ritesh. Thank yo for your reply. Glad that you have solved the problem!